# How to insert metatag without using jquery append?

Tags: javascript, append, meta-tags, getelementsbytagname

I used the following jquery to insert a metatag into a html document.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(screen.width>=320 && screen.width<=767){
$('head').append('<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">');}    
</script>
```

**If possible, I'd like to insert the metatag without using jquery. Anyone have any ideas how I can do that?**

I believe I will probably need to use document.getElementByTagName but I'm not sure how.

Just in case you are wondering, I am inserting the metatag into my html to to optomize the site for viewing with the iphone.
Unfortunately, width=device-width is not an option as it doesn't play well with my ipad version.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you sure mobile devices run your Javascript before checking out the Meta tag?

Comment: I've tested it on the ipad and the iphone and it works. Good question though. I'm not sure about any other devices. I will try android later.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. I'm finding that the iphone is not consistently detecting the metatag (At least I think that is the problem). Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. I think that I will use php instead and just redirect to a mobile specific page.

Comment: I noticed that semicolons in the "content" attr are wrong, should be commas: "width=320, initial-scale=1, ..."

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
var viewPortTag=document.createElement('meta');
viewPortTag.id="viewport";
viewPortTag.name = "viewport";
viewPortTag.content = "width=320, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewPortTag);
```

Answer (score 6):

Javascript solution:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += '<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">';
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use "setAttribute" (rather than the "dot" notation) for weirdo attribute names (that contain non-alpha-numeric characters).

Example:

```
var iefix=document.createElement('meta');
iefix.setAttribute("http-equiv", "X-UA-Compatible");
iefix.setAttribute("content", "IE=Edge");
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(iefix);
```

The example above causes IE (<=9) to always use the latest document standards mode. Sometimes IE will fall back to older standards, and therefore break your modern javascript / canvas web app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that creates a meta tag, if it does not already exist:

```
var viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');
var viewportContent = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0';

if (viewport === null) {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  viewport = document.createElement('meta');
  viewport.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
  head.appendChild(viewport);
}

viewport.setAttribute('content', viewportContent);
```